# Smoothing by bin boundaries using pandas/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-mining, smoothing

I have formed the bins using pandas.cut function. Now, in order to perform smoothing by bin-boundaries, I calculate the minimum and maximum value of each bin using groupby function
Minimum values

```
    date    births  with noise
bin         
A   1959-01-31  23  19.921049
B   1959-01-02  27  25.921175
C   1959-01-01  30  32.064698
D   1959-01-08  35  38.507170
E   1959-01-05  41  45.022163
F   1959-01-13  47  51.821755
G   1959-03-27  56  59.416700
H   1959-09-23  73  70.140119
```

Maximum values-

```
    date    births  with noise
bin         
A   1959-07-12  30  25.161292
B   1959-12-11  35  31.738422
C   1959-12-27  42  38.447807
D   1959-12-20  48  44.919703
E   1959-12-31  56  51.274550
F   1959-12-30  59  57.515927
G   1959-11-05  68  63.970382
H   1959-09-23  73  70.140119
```

Now I want to replace the values in my original dataframe. If the value is less than the mean (of its bin) then it is replaced with the min value (for that bin), and if it is greater than the mean then it is replaced with the max value.
My dataframe looks like this-

```
    date    births  with noise  bin smooth_val_mean
0   1959-01-01  35  36.964692   C   35.461173
1   1959-01-02  32  29.861393   B   29.592061
2   1959-01-03  30  27.268515   B   29.592061
3   1959-01-04  31  31.513148   B   29.592061
4   1959-01-05  44  46.194690   E   47.850101
```

How should I do this using pandas/numpy?

Comment: You showed the `max/min` values for each bins, but I don't see the mean. Also, do you want to replace both `births` and `with noise` columns?

Comment: Similar to the max/min values I have calculated the means beforehand too. And, just the "with noise" column. (Or maybe both, I'm just looking for the procedure). @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this function:

```
def thresh(col):
    means = df['bin'].replace(df_mean[col])
    mins = df['bin'].replace(df_min[col])
    maxs = df['bin'].replace(df_max[col])
    
    signs = np.signs(df[col] - means)
    
    df[f'{col}_smooth'] = np.select((signs==1, signs==-1), (maxs, mins), means)

for col in ['with noise']:
    thresh(col)
```

Comment: The statement ```signs = df[col] - means``` is giving the error- " Object with dtype category cannot perform the numpy op subtract"

Comment: @SatashreeRoy try using `replace` instead of `map`. See updates.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. However, I am confused about ```signs```. What if it's other than 1 or -1? (For eg, I observed few datapoint giving signs= ~2 ). I would still like the value to be smoothed by any of the boundary value, not mean. @QuangHoang

Comment: @SatashreeRoy sorry, it should be wrapped by `np.signs` which returns `1,0,-1` when the values are positives, 0, negative respectively. See updates.